# htaccess serving chunks from subfolder

Tags: .htaccess, cpanel

i am trying to use such build structure uploading to cpanel

[image]

all my scripts are in static folder but when opening my site it throws

> main.f2a553.js:1          GET https://mysite/448.448.2858b0.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404

main script is trying to load chunks from root folder but i want to load them from static folder

how can i write a htaccess rule to redirect all requests from main script file to static subfolder

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution here
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/rewrite/remapping.html
and added this to the htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on

#   first try to find resource in static/...
RewriteCond         "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/static/%{REQUEST_URI}"  -f
RewriteRule "^(.+)" "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/static/$1"  [L]

RewriteRule "^"     "-"
```

Comment: That last `RewriteRule` directive is redundant.